# How to change color of a Window (Problems with Buffer Strategy )

Tags: java

I have been trying to  follow a simple tutorial online(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws). When I  try to enter the  code that he  enters I  don't get the same results.  Some things that I type end up as  errors that it can't  use. It  happens  particularly  when I  try to  use GetBufferStrategy. I'm  not quite sure what is  wrong with my code.  I could really use some help.

Here's what I've got :

```
    package components;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.LayoutManager;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    /* FrameDemo.java requires no other files. */
    public class Window {
        /**
         * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
         * this method should be invoked from the
         * event-dispatching thread.
         */

        private Thread thread;
        private boolean running = false;



        public synchronized void start(){

            thread = new Thread();
            thread.start();
            running = true;

        }

        public synchronized void stop(){

            try{
                thread.join();
                running=false;
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void run(){


                long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
                double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
                double delta = 0;
                long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int frames = 0;
                while(running)
                {
                            long now = System.nanoTime();
                            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                            lastTime = now;
                            while(delta >=1)
                                    {
                                        tick();
                                        delta--;
                                    }
                                    if(running)
                                        render();
                                    frames++;

                                    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
                                    {
                                        timer += 1000;
                                        System.out.println("FPS: "+ frames);
                                        frames = 0;
                                    }
                }
                        stop();


        }

        private void tick(){

        }

        private void render() {
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();

            if (bs==null){
                this.createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;         
            }

            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0,0,873,374);

            g.dispose();
            bs.show();
        }

        private void createBufferStrategy(int i) {


        }

        private BufferStrategy getBufferStrategy() {

        return null;
        }

        private static void createAndShowGUI() {
            //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mr. Krebs");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
            emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
            frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            //Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
            //creating and showing this application's GUI.
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: IMHO video tutorials are a format that is ill suited for learning programming. Simple things like scrolling up and down through the code to look at other parts of the code simply don't work well in a video.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please add all needed information directly here on stack overflow.

Comment: I want to  know how to  create just  basic  graphics  in a  window.  At the current  moment I'm  only trying to  turn the  screen of the  window  to  black.  Though at this  point that doesn't even seem to be responsive.  My question  really is what am  I  doing wrong and  how can I  fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend `Canvas`:

```
public class Window extends Canvas {
     ...
}
```

In your `render()` method you're using `this.getBufferStrategy` and `this.createBufferStrategy`. Since those two instructions calls methods that are in the `Canvas` class if you don't type `extends Canvas`, you'll get errors because those methods can't be found.

Comment: Thank you  that  helps. Now I have no  errors.  However  with the code that I  have I  believe that I should have a black screen  and  at the current moment my screen is  unchanged.